# Трехдневный

Tags: орфография, числительные

Попалось в тексте "3-хдневный семинар". Правильно написано или нет? Что-то я не могу сообразить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, неправильно, буква "х" здесь не к месту. Вообще, смешивание цифр и букв не всегда желательно. Лучше написать словом "трехдневный", или "3-дневный",или "семинар продлится 3 дня"

Comment: Читала историю. В давнее время, когда не было персональных компьютеров, объявления печатались на пишущей машинке. А там латинских букв нет. Так что про пятнадцатую олимпиаду написали так: "... на ХУ-й олимпиаде ...". Конфуз !!!  

> В.А.Успенский. Труды по НЕматематике.

Comment: Божежь... Он что, собирает старые анекдоты?

Comment: Нет, это была история математико-лингвистических олимпиад. Как организовывались, проходили, какие были трудности.  

Выбор материала - мой, и претензии ко мне.

Comment: Да я эту историю слышал году в 67-м. Про XV-й съезд ВЛКСМ.
 
Надо ж. Почти угадал: май 1966 г. 
ЗЫ правило о буквенных наращения не рапространяется на порядковые числительные, записанные римскими цифрами.

Comment: Ну, такая история могла и повториться. Успенский говорит не о легенде, о факте. Впрочем, с этим - к нему. Олимпиады были попозже.  

А к римским цифрам вообще нельзя наращивать? У того же В.А. обсуждается написание "патриарх Алексий II-ой". Говорит, что так нельзя, получается "одиннадцатый" ))

Comment: Нет, наращивать ничего нельзя. Римские цифры самодостаточны. Ими обозначают только порядковые числительные, причем очень ограниченного списка.

Кстати, а что заничи вообще ничего? Наращения и так используются только для передачи окончаний порядковых. Ни для чего более.

Answer (score 2):

ТРЁХДНЕВНЫЙ - прилагательное. Прилагательные в официальных документах заменять цифрами не следует! Только числительные.

1. Буквенным способом оформляются в тексте однозначные количественные числительные во всех случаях, кроме употребления их при единицах физических величин, например: два урока, три сестры, девять морей. При единицах физических величин буквенный способ сохраняется, если величина дается словом: четыре джоуля и заменяется на цифровой, если величина дается в принятом сокращении: 4 Дж.
2. Цифровым способом оформляются количественные числительные в таблицах, схемах, диаграммах, формулах и т.п. Этим же способом оформляются порядковые числительные, если они даны римскими цифрами. Но использование римских цифр для обозначения порядковых числительных ограничено: они применяются только при существительных век, столетие, ассамблея, конгресс, съезд, конференция и подобного типа, например: XX век, XX столетие, VII съезд народных депутатов.
3. Смешанным способом могут оформляться и количественные, и порядковые числительные. Количественные числительные, обозначающие круглые числа – тысячи, миллионы, миллиарды рекомендуется писать в виде сочетания цифр с полными или сокращенными обозначениями: 30 тысяч участников, 30 млн. тонн продовольствия. Порядковые числительные, обозначаемые арабскими цифрами, имеют наращение, например: 2-е издание. Если порядковые числительные следуют одно за другим, то наращение ставят при последней цифре: в 1, 3 и 8-м пунктах. Наращение состоит из одной буквы, если предпоследняя буква гласная – в 5-м разделе, в 1-й главе и двух, если предпоследняя буква согласная – из 2-го издания. ***Смешанным способом могут оформляться и сложные прилагательные, если их первой частью является числительное, а второй метрическая мера, процент или другая единица величины, например: 15-литровый, 12-метровый, 20-тонный, 10-процентный.***

Примечание. Недопустимы наращения при количественных числительных, обозначениях дат, а также при римских цифрах: из 25 участников, 24 мая, VII съезд.  (http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/31.htm)

Comment: Как раз сейчас пишу задачу про 2012-угольник. Тут уж словами не обойдешься! Кстати, треугольник, четырехугольник, пятиугольник никто цифрами не пишет. Но вот уже восемнадцатиугольник, пожалуй, лучше обозначить как 18-угольник (кстати, у меня на экране слово подчеркнуто красным). Или это касается только "многословных" числительных? Например 53-угольник буквами записать трудно.  

Кстати, а как записать 53-дневный промежуток времени? Тоже буквами?

Comment: DocentI, всё у вас правилно.
Насчет восемнадцатиугольника - не заню, и так и так можно. До двадцатиодноугольника где-то. Но в математическом тексте можно и N-угольник. (Где N вполне может быть рано 3).

Comment: Попадает под третье правило, день - это единица измерения величины (времени).

Answer (score 0):

Буквенные наращения (1-й, 3-го и т.д.) используются только при написании порядковых числительных. Во всех остальных случаях, в том числе и при написании составного прилагательного (количественно-субстантного? - можно так назвать?) они не нужны.

При использовании буквенно-цифрового способа написания цифрами ципррами записывается числительное, субстантная основа - буквами: 3-дневный.

~ ~ ~
Вопрос № 266499

Как написать словесно-цифровым способом "трехтомный", "двухроликовый"?
Спасибо.
lubaluba
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Правильно: 3-томный, 2-роликовый.

Грамота.